# Easier way of doing combinations Django

Tags: django, django-views

Is there any easy way of doing this. I think i missing some combination.

```
    search = request.GET.get(u'search')
    cities = request.POST.getlist(u'cities')
    countries = request.POST.getlist(u'countries')

    if search and cities and counties:
        self.object_list = self.get_queryset().filter(title__icontains=search, country__icontains=counties,
                                                      city__icontains=cities,)
    elif search and cities:
        self.object_list = self.get_queryset().filter(title__icontains=search, city__icontains=cities,)
    elif search and counties:
        self.object_list = self.get_queryset().filter(title__icontains=search, country__icontains=counties,)
    elif cities and counties:
        self.object_list = self.get_queryset().filter(country__icontains=counties, city__icontains=cities,)
    elif search:
        self.object_list = self.get_queryset().filter(title__icontains=search,)
    elif search:
        self.object_list = self.get_queryset().filter(title__icontains=search,)
    else:
        self.object_list = self.get_queryset()
```

Basically passing only the fields that are selected.

Here is the form

```
search = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Looking For ...'}), required=False)
countries = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=Legs.objects.values_list('country', flat=True).distinct(),
                                          widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple(), required=False)
cities = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=Legs.objects.values_list('city', flat=True).distinct(),
                                        widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple(), required=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can chain the `filter()` calls:

```
self.object_list = self.get_queryset()

if search:
    self.object_list = self.object_list.filter(title__icontains=search)
if cities:
    self.object_list = self.object_list.filter(city__icontains=cities)
if countries:
    self.object_list = self.object_list.filter(country__icontains=countries)
```

Comment: How di i pass list like multiple checked item to filter?

Comment: For multiple items use the Q objects: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do it is to create a dictionary of your filters and then decompose it in your call to `filter`.

```
filters = {}

if search:
    filters['title__icontains'] = search
if cities:
    filters['city__icontains'] =cities
if countries:
    filters['country__icontains'] =countries
self.object_list = self.get_queryset().filter(**filters)
```

Comment: Can you please check again. I think my logic is wrong. Because the cities and coutries and multiple checkbox. if click first item it work fine but for multiple item it does not

Comment: I think you might be able to use ```__in``` instead of ```__icontains``` for the city and country then.

Comment: yes that worked for me thanks, secondly when i do get the form became default. is there any way to keep the selected data? Or i have to find a work around.

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. However it doesn't quite seem related to this question in particular, so maybe create a new one?